# Getting started with REST JSON request

Tags: python, json, api

I'm in dire need of getting started with REST JSON API, possibly with python. 
Already purchased the subscription to use the API. How can I make a REST request?

Below is an excerpt from the [documentation](http://wiki.melissadata.com/index.php?title=SmartMover_V3%3AREST_JSON).

**REST Request**

```
https://smartmover.melissadata.net/v3/WEB/SmartMover/doSmartMover
?t={Transmission Reference}
&id={License Key}
&jobid={Job ID}
&pafid={PAF ID}
&act={Actions}
&cols={Columns}
&opt={Options}
&List={List Name}
&comp={Company}
&full={Name Full}
&first={Name First}
&Middle={Name Middle}
&Namepre={Name Prefix}
&Namesfx={Name Suffix}
&last={Name Last}
&u={Urbanization}
&a1={Address Line 1}
&a2={Address Line 2}
&ste={Suite}
&pmb={Private Mailbox}
&city={City}
&state={State}
&postal={Postal Code}
&plus4={Plus4}
&ctry={Country}
&format={Format}
```

Thanks for any help!!!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you already familiar with REST as a concept? Are you already familiar with Python as a language? If not, consider searching for some tutorials on those two topics, then follow up with a tutorial on the two together.

Comment: Also, Postman is practically a must if you try to consume an API. Postman is an app which you can use to test your requests while programming them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, and opinion-based, but I'll give you some directions to seek:

1. First of all, just get some grasp of HTTP and REST API concepts overall. Wiki may be a good starting point
2. If your looking for non-programmatic HTTP API client, take a look at [httpie](https://httpie.org/). The good thins is that it gives you a glimpse of what's going on lower-ish level, while maintaining really good balance of detail vs simple interface (not grapic interface, tho). As a bonus, its written in python
3. For programmatic use (this is probably what you looking for), I suggest using [`requests` library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/). It has *awesome* interface, and IMO it's standard de-facto in modern python. Easy to use, easy to understand how to use it with your API, handles a lot of routine stuff for you, easy to subclass/inherit.